# C++ project with Objective-C++ framework import fails to build

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, objective-c++

I have a CMake C++ project which targets mac, which has a `.h` header file that includes the following import.

```mm
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from /Users/ram/development/foo/mac/FooComponent.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:492:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString, Protocol;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:503:50: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:504:19: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol * _Nullable NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:508:53: error: format argument not an NSString
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^                  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:94:49: note: expanded from macro 'NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION'
        #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
                                                       ^                    ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:509:63: error: format argument not an NSString
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                ^                  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:94:49: note: expanded from macro 'NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION'
        #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
                                                       ^                    ~
```

I've tried updating the project's CMakeLists.txt to pass `"-framework Foundation" but somehow CMake filters out that library from the build.

Does anyone know what might be the root cause, and how to fix it?

Comment: I have the impression that the compiler here did not understand source is in Objective-C. From which source did you include `Foundation.h` ? It should work from a `.mm` or a `.m` file, but surely not from a `.cpp` source file.

Comment: @prapin `Foundation.h` is included in the project's `FooComponent.h` header file, which features a `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

Comment: OK, but which source file includes `FooComponent.h` ? A header is never compiled separately.